# Is this lemma missing hypotheses?

Tags: general-topology

I had a class today and one lemma was left as an exercise, the statment is that given topological spaces $W$ and $Z$, and a continous and closed function $\nu:W\rightarrow Z$, let $S\subset Z$ and an open set $U\subset W$, such $\nu^{-1}(S)\subset U$, then there is an open subset $V\subset Z$ such that $S\subset V$ and $\nu^{-1}(V)\subset U$.

At first, I tried to proof this by contradiction, supposing that for all open sets $S\subset V$, then $\nu^{-1}(V)\nsubseteq U$, then there is an $x\in \nu^{-1}(V)\cap U^c$, then $\nu(v)\in V\cap \nu(U^c)$, and $\nu(U^c)$ is closed, but I can not do anything else there.

So I tried to look at this relation $\nu(\nu^{-1}(S))\subset S\subset \bar S\subset \nu(\bar U)$  and use that the map is closed to find the open inside of $\bar U$, but again I was not able.

So I started to think that maybe there is some hypotheses missing, is this lemma right? If it is, how could I try to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you've written it correctly? Since $S\subset Z$ then $\nu^{-1}(S)$ doesn't always make much sense as $S$ is a subset of the domain of $\nu$, not the range.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fixed, the function was from $W$ to $Z$, thanks

Comment: No hypothesis missing (and the continuity of $\nu$ isn't required, only its closedness). What do you know about $\nu(W\setminus U)$?

Comment: Daniel, it is closed, then if I consider $V=\nu(U^c)^c$ it follows that $\nu^{-1}(V)\subset U$, and that $S\subset V$, it is right?

Comment: Yes. What is the proof of $S \subset V$?

Comment: I got it here, if I take a $x\in S$, then $\nu^{-1}(x)\subset \nu^{-1}(S)\subset U$, then $x \in \nu(U)$, then applying complementar $U^c\subset \nu^{-1}(x)^c$, I can pass the complementar inside of $\nu^{-1}$, and applying $\nu$ i get $\nu(U^c)\subset\nu(\nu^{-1}(\{x\}^c))\subset \{x\}^c$, then $x\in V$. If you want to submit the answer I'll give you the right solution. Thanks so much

Comment: Is V closed? Open?

Comment: I fixed, $V$ must be open, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hypothesis missing.

If $U \subset W$ is open with $\nu^{-1}(S) \subset U$, then $F = W\setminus U$ is closed, and $\nu(F) \cap S = \varnothing$. Since $\nu$ is closed, $\nu(F)$ is a closed set, and hence $V = Z\setminus \nu(F)$ is an open set with $S\subset V$. And $\nu^{-1}(V) \subset U$ since $V = Z\setminus \nu(W\setminus U)$.

In fact, this property characterises closed maps. Let $f \colon W \to Z$ a map such that for every $S \subset Z$ and every open $U \subset W$ with $f^{-1}(S) \subset U$ there is an open $V\subset Z$ with $S \subset V$ and $f^{-1}(V) \subset U$. Then $f$ is a closed map.

For let $F\subset W$ a closed set. Then for $S := Z \setminus f(F)$ we have $f^{-1}(S) \subset U := W\setminus F$, and by assumption there is an open $V\subset Z$ with $S\subset V$ and $f^{-1}(V) \subset U$. But the latter implies $V \cap f(F) = \varnothing$, and hence $V \subset S$. Thus $S = V$ is open, and $f(F) = Z\setminus S$ is closed.